# How to bootstrap time series data

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, bootstrap, bagging

I have this dataset that contains multiple series (50 products). My dataset has 50 products (50 columns). each column contains the monthly sales of a product. I recently learned about bootstrap and how it can improve forecast accuracy. Therefore, I decided to compare the results that I will get when using ets, Arima, and when using bootstrapping method. Here is my code and I would love if someone can help me understand how to apply bootstrap on a time series and how to use it with other forecasting techniques. So far I've used `ets` and `Arima` without bootstrap and now I want to use bootstrapping and then compare the results of each method and prove which one is the best method to forecast time series.

```r
library(fable)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
y <- ts(matrix(rnorm(175*50), ncol=50), frequency=12, start=c(2007,1)) %>%
  as_tsibble() %>%
  rename(Month = index, Sales=value)
fit.ets <- y %>% model(ETS(Sales))  
fit.ets
f.ets <- forecast(fit.ets, h=12)
f.ets
```

Comment: Bootstrap is not a forecasting technique in itself, unlike ARIMA or exponential smoothing. Where did you get the idea to apply bootstrap for forecasting?

Comment: Sorry,  I meant using ets and arma after bootstrapping the time series data. Does it make sense?  I want to bootstrap the time series first then use forecasting technique and compare it with the results I will get when forecasting the sales without bootstrapping

Comment: You probably mean bootstrap aggregation (a.k.a. bagging) combined with time series techniques such as ARIMA or exponential smoothing. The `forecast` package in R might contain a function that does `ets` + bagging. There is a [paper](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/BaggedETSForIJF_rev1.pdf) and, I think, a blog post by Rob J. Hyndman about `ets` + bagging and how it works very well on M3 competition data. See [this](https://otexts.com/fpp3/bootstrap.html) chapter of the FPP textbook.

Comment: Check out the textbook chapter/section I have referenced, it includes plotting.

Comment: Basically, I want to plot the time series of each product and then plot the time series of each product after we apply the bootstrap method. So, for each product, I want to do 100 replication with replacement and then plot the results and compare it with the plots of the original time series. and then I want to use the bagging time series and combine it with ets. I am new to both statistics and r and I did  look at the paper you sent before but I could understand them that's why I want to try this on a small dataset

Comment: For an easier approach, follow the textbook, not the papers. Now, it seems you are asking for R code to do what you want to do. That would be off topic. But you can ask conceptual questions, like, what should I do or how (conceptually) do I achieve something (not *how I should do what I want in R*).

Comment: The aim of my question is how to do it in R hence the reason why I also added my code. As I said before I read these articles and didn’t understand the concept very well and therefore I have Created a dataset using rnorm() and want to observe the changes myself. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, that is off topic. I would try rereading the textbook chapter/section and the code therein to figure out how to adapt it to your setting.

Comment: Hi, I did exactly as you told me but still unable to figure it out, Could you help me please: This my code                                                                                                           y <- ts(matrix(rnorm(175*50), ncol=50), frequency=12, start=c(2007,1)) %>%
  as_tsibble() %>%
  rename(Month = index, Sales=value)
sales <- y %>%
  select(Month, Sales)
sales_stl <- sales  %>%
  model(stl = STL(Sales))
  sales_stl %>%
  components() %>%
  autoplot()     the error I get when running the code: Error in STL(Sales) : could not find function "STL"

Comment: `y <- ts(matrix(rnorm(175*50), ncol=50), frequency=12, start=c(2007,1)) %>% as_tsibble() %>% rename(Month = index, Sales=value)                                                sales <- y %>% select(Month, Sales)                                                                        sales_stl <- sales %>% model(stl = STL(Sales)) sales_stl %>% components() %>% autoplot()                                                                                                        sales_stl %>% generate(new_data = sales, times = 100, bootstrap_block_size = 24) %>% autoplot(.sim) + autolayer(sales, Sales)`

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is no function `STL`, there is only `stl`.

Comment: Hi Richard Thanks for your prompt reply, in the book they have used STL but I've used both STL and stl and non of them worked

Comment: I do not work with pipes or tidyverse myself, so I find it hard to comment on what exactly went wrong here. Consider creating a minimal reproducible example to isolate the error and make it replicable.

Comment: Please do **not** post code (or error messages) in the comments - they are literally unreadable! Edit & update your post accordingly, if necessary.

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean bootstrap aggregation (a.k.a. bagging) combined with time series techniques such as ARIMA or exponential smoothing. There is a [paper](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/BaggedETSForIJF_rev1.pdf)* and [another one](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/exploring-sources-uncertainty.pdf)** about `ets` + bagging and how it works very well on M3 competition data. See [this](https://otexts.com/fpp3/bootstrap.html) section of the "Forecasting Principles and Practice" textbook for a brief overview with R code and an example application.

*Bergmeir, Hyndman and Benitez ["Bagging Exponential Smoothing Methods using STL Decomposition and Box-Cox Transformation"](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/BaggedETSForIJF_rev1.pdf) (2016)
**Petropoulos, Hyndman and Bergmeir ["Exploring the sources of uncertainty: why does bagging for time series forecasting work?"](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/exploring-sources-uncertainty.pdf) (2018)